# Getting not defined on factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, factory-pattern

I am trying to use ionic with angular to pass data from one controller to anther,
I know that the best way to do it with factory, 
But I am getting error:

> ReferenceError: setData is not defined

my code is

```
app.factory("Places", function() {
    var Places = {};
    Places.setData = function(places) {
      Places.items = places;
    };
     Places.getItem = function($stateParams) {
      return Places.item;
    };

    return{
        setData: setData,
        getItem:getItem
    }
  })
```

and the controler

```
   .controller('DetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams,Places) {
          console.log('PlaceitemCtrl');
        $scope.items=Places.getItem($stateParams);
    });
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Where do you call setData?

Comment: return  { setData: Places.setData, getItem: Places.getItem } or return { places: Places }

Comment: Why are you returning a new object, instead of `Places`? there's no variable `setData` defined in your function, so you're essentially returning { setData: undefiend, getItem: undefined }. Consider using strict mode to catch these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning new object from the factory and at the same time there are no local `setData` and `getItem` functions defined. Instead return `Places` object which has necessary methods attached:

```
app.factory("Places", function () {
    var Places = {};
    Places.setData = function (places) {
        Places.items = places;
    };
    Places.getItem = function ($stateParams) {
        return Places.item;
    };

    return Places;
});
```

Comment: one more issue whey when I am doing refresh to the page I am not getting agian this values?

Comment: Because you refresh the page, and application gets reinitialized with all the services/controllers/everything created recreated again. If you need some persistence you need to use localStorage for example.

Comment: correct! Thnx, do you think it possible to get refresh on the page if its android app or iphone app? I dont think its possible with using ionic